# Почему переменная всегда undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

В моем приложении функция loginApp возвращает значение, присваиваемое глобальной (в файле) переменной currentUser, которое я затем использую. Почему undefined записывается в currentUser? Как мне исправить это, чтобы оно работало так, как я ожидал? Мне нужно знать пользователя, который вошел в мое приложение сразу после того, как он это сделал.

auth.js:

```js
function loginApp(request, response) {
    let body = ''

    request.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString('utf8')
    })

    request.on('end', async () => {
        let answer = ''

        try {
            let params = JSON.parse(body)
            const user = await User.findOne({username: params['username']})
            
            if (!user) {
                answer = `User ${params['username']} not found`
                response.end(JSON.stringify({message: answer}))
            }

            const validPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(params['password'], user.password)
            if (!validPassword) {
                answer = 'Incorrect username or password entered '
                response.end(JSON.stringify({message: answer}))
            }
            else {
                answer = 'User exists'
                response.end(JSON.stringify({message: answer}))
                return params['username'];
            }

        } catch (ex) {
        }
    })
}
```

index.js:

```js
let currentUser;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

...

    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        ...
        if (req.url === '/login') {
            currentUser = loginApp(req, res);
        }
        ...
    else if (req.method === 'GET') {
        // дальше я хочу использовать currentUser, но:
        console.log("currentUser: " + currentUser); // undefined
        ...
    }
...
})
```

Я знаю, что здесь дело в синхронности. В то время как мне надо сделать это асинхронно, но я не знаю как это сделать. Может быть, найдутся те, кто знает?

Comment: Нет проблем с тем, что вы присваиваете значение переменной в одной ветке `if..else`, а проверяете это значение в другой?

Comment: @br3t, а как ещё я верну значение из функции, которая отрабатывает по пост-запросу, а значение, которое она возвращает, нужно в гет-запросе? это чистый node js, не express, поэтому приходится чудить

Comment: У Вас `loginApp` ничего не возвращает, поэтому результатом ее вызова всегда и будет `undefined`. Возвращайте хотя бы промис.

Comment: @Yaant, можете подробнее об этом?

Comment: `function loginApp(...) { return new Promise(resolve => {...; request.on('end', async () => {...; resolve(params['username'); ,,,})})}`. Как-то так, если навскидку.